# I am working On SQL query but not working full outer join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to work on SQL. inner join is not working missing. I am using two tables get data on "city_id " field these table    code so please help me

```
inventory
==========================================
inventory_id | city_id | title |is_enabled
==========================================
          1  |       1 |  abc  | 1
          2  |       1 | bcd   | 1



cities
====================================
city_id | city  | title
===================================
     1  | delhi |  abc
     2  | nodia |  bcd


   SELECT * FROM inventory i 

                INNER JOIN  cities c 

                ON i.city_id = c.city_id 

                WHERE i.is_enabled = 1 

                ORDER BY i.inventory_id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Some databases (such as MS Access and MySQL) do not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

However, `FULL OUTER JOIN` is rarely needed -- and almost never when you are using keys defined between tables.  Well structured databases have keys with appropriate values.

I suspect an `INNER JOIN` does what you want:

```
SELECT . . .   -- list out the columns you want
FROM inventory i INNER JOIN
     cities c
     ON i.city_id = c.city_id
WHERE i.is_enabled = 1
ORDER BY i.inventory_id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This query assumes that the `inventory` rows have a valid `city_id`.  If some are `NULL` (an allowed, non-matching value), you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Some other notes:

- List out the columns you want explicitly.  In particular, duplicate column names can be problematic.
- Use table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names.  I'm guessing that `is_enabled` comes from `inventory`.  I should not have to guess.
- Do not put single quotes around numeric constants.  I am guessing that `is_enabled` is a number, not a string.

Comment: yes sir is_enabled number, not a string but user only inventory table